# Специфическое объединение двух коллекций

Tags: коллекции

Хочу решить красиво задачу изменения коллекции (без if-ов и циклов):

У пользователя есть список животных. У животного есть только имя и оно опционально.
Пользователь может создать список, присвоить животному имя (или не присвоить)
И, что самое главное, пользователь может задать размер списка, при чем если размер больше чем есть у списка сейчас, в список добавляются животные с пустыми именами (которые могут быть заполнены позже), а если меньше, то текущий список с животными должен уменьшиться до этого размера.

Тут можно сделать довольно простое процедурное решение с проверкой того, больше выставленный размер текущего списка или меньше и в зависимости от этого мы или удаляем из коллекции n элементов или добавляем n пустых элементов.
Но мне это не нравится.

Я бы хотел взять текущий список, создать пустой список из кол-ва элементов, заданных размером списка и сделать специфическое объединение, которое бы вернуло мне то что нужно.

Пример:
Текущая коллекция животных: `{ A, B, C }`
Пользователь меняет размер до 5-ти:
Создаем пустую коллекцию (E - Empty): `{E, E, E, E, E}` 
Обединяем: `specialMerge({A, B, C}, {E, E, E, E, E})` 
Результат объединения:

```
{A, B, C, E, E}
```

Изменяем размер до 2-х:

```
specialMerge({A, B, C, E, E}, {E, E})
```

Результат объединения:

```
{A, B}
```

Никаких if-ов и циклов! Красота! Только вот где мне найти такой объединительный метод?

Т.е. мне интересно, может есть в природе такое объединение и у него есть название и какая-нибудь библиотечная реализация (на любом языке, хотя я бы отдал предпочтение JVM языкам (Scala, Java, Clojure, Groovy)), или это мои фантазии?)

Comment: _Никаких if-ов и циклов!_ - эм, эти if-ы и циклы будут же _внутри_ этой функции _specialMerge_, так какая разница?

Comment: Я не ставлю if-ы вне закона и не возражаю, если какая-то библиотечная функция их использует. Главное - что бы в моем коде, с которым я непосредственно работаю изо дня в день, их было поменьше. Я бы сказал, что это вопрос вкуса и стиля. Если можно писать без условий - я стараюсь писать без них. То что if-ы будут внутри specialMerge меня не особенно волнует, т.к. я рассматриваю этот вызов как вызов библиотечой функции, внутренности которой инкапсулированы и по большому счету не должны меня заботить (за исключением редких случаев).

Comment: я вел к том, что если написать _свою_ функцию, то чем она будет отличаться от _библиотечной_?

Comment: в общем случае, для решения можно использовать метод `map`, для коллекции E, в котором возвращать элементы из текущей коллекции, пока индекс это позволяет, в противном случае возвращать E. Либо аналогично использовать `reduce`(`fold`)

Comment: Хотя бы тем, что if-ы будут ограничены этой функцией и не будут дальше расползаться по коду (хотя формально как раз эта функция с if-ами и будет вызываться, но, повторюсь, я этого уже не увижу, т.к. они скрыты за вызовом)

Comment: еще можно использовать функции генераторы (не уверен, что они есть в перечисленных предпочтительных языках)

Comment: _Хотя бы тем, что if-ы будут ограничены этой функцией и не будут дальше расползаться по коду_ - ну так какая разница if внутри библиотечной функции или if внутри твоей функции, если ты все равно будешь вызывать _функцию_ и не важно что внутри.

Comment: @VasiliyHaskellov может тогда вам лучше Haskel или Lisp подойдут?

Comment: @Sublihim, какая разница? _Clojure_ - почти lisp

Comment: @Grundy так неужели там нет элегантной работы со списками

Comment: @Sublihim, элегантность - вещь относительная

Comment: @Grundy тут я не спорю.

Comment: _я вел к том, что если написать свою функцию, то чем она будет отличаться от библиотечной?_
Да в принципе ни чем. Просто было интересно узнать, вдруг есть в природе такое "специфическое" объединение

Comment: @Sublihim не силен в этих языках :)

Comment: Хотя не, все проще: просто объединяешь списки, (список со значениями дополняешь списком пустых значений) а затем берешь N первых элементов

Comment: Поторопился отмечать, может еще кто-то предложит варианты

Comment: @Grundy _может еще кто-то предложит варианты_ мне сложно представить более простое и элегантное решение, чем ваше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное самый простой подход:

1. Дополнить исходную коллекцию со значениями, списком с N пустыми значениями
2. Взять первые N элементов получившейся коллекции

На lisp это может выглядеть так:

```lisp
(subseq (append values (make-list N :initial-element 'empty)) 0 N)
```

Где `values` - Это список элементов, `N` - количество элементов в результирующем списке, `'empty` - пустой элемент

Comment: Да! Именно то, чего я хотел, но до чего не смог додуматься! И необходимости в "специфическом" объединении нет никакой!